# How to re-install Jetpack Joyride after uninstalling?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I recently uninstalled Jetpack Joyride as it would not open after the recent update (after remaining on the loading screen for several minutes it would cut back to my home screen without opening), assuming that I would be able to reinstall this app from the Google Play Android Apps store.

When I go the the Free download Jetpack Joyride page on the Google Play store it has a button saying "Installed" and no option to reinstall. Does anyone know how to inform the Google Play app store that the app has been uninstalled?

Can I reinstall the free app? If so, how? Or do I now need to buy it?

Thanks.

Comment: You mention both Google Play and the Samsung store - which one?

Comment: It says Android Apps on Google Play. So Google Play.

Comment: How did you uninstall it?  Sounds like you uninstalled it in a rather unorthodox manner.

Comment: @user52557 - Read your question again - you mention both Google Play and Samsung App store. Just edit it out, to clear confusion.

Comment: I went into Settings, then into Manage Apps, tapped the Jetpack Joyride app icon then pressed Uninstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/how-can-i-force-the-market-to-reinstall-an-installed-app) on Android.stackexchange.com it looks like you cannot force a re-installation through the market, but what you can do is try to force the Market app itself to re-synchronise your installed apps.

Go to 
`Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> All -> Market` and select `Force Close` and `Clear Data`, then restart your phone and open the Market app. This may work, but is not guaranteed.